# Not able to integrate MailChimp with my WordPress Site

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, custom-wordpress-pages, web-frontend, web-forms-for-marketers

I have created a new website using wordpress and elementor pro. Main purpose of building this website is to collect email IDs. 
In return on email ID, I’m giving away an opt in. 
The problem I’m having is when someone enters their email ID and clicks on “Sign up”, the opt in I have created in templates of mail chimp isn’t going in their mailbox (not even in spam). 
I believe the issue to linking the opt in with that form. I’m not sure. 
Can someone please guide me how do I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Is your Server mail is working. Are you able to get the test mail. If server mail is working then are you getting any error while doing sign up or any success or failure message

Answer (score 1):

When they click "sign up" the form is not supposed to send an email to you, it is supposed to send that user/email to your MailChimp list on MailChimp.com. 
Therefore first check if the information goes to your MailChimp. If it does, you can then contact MailChimp support to get help on how to configure email notifications once a user is added to a list.

And if it is not sending to your list then the issue may be with your setup/API/plugin. We cannot troubleshoot that without a login access or link.